# Why instance variable in rspec is nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have this code:

```
  before(:all) { @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
  byebug
  subject { @user }
  it { should respond_to(:email)}
  it { should respond_to(:password)}
  it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation)}


  it { should be_valid }

  it { should validate_presence_of(:email) }

  it { should validate_confirmation_of(:password) }
  it { should allow_value('example@domain.com').for(:email)}

  describe 'validations' do
    subject { FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
    it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:email).case_insensitive}
  end
```

When it stops after byebug, it discovers that @user is nil:

```
    1: require 'rails_helper'
    2: 
    3: describe User do
    4:   before(:all) { @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
    5:   byebug
=>  6:   subject { @user }
    7:   it { should respond_to(:email)}
    8:   it { should respond_to(:password)}
    9:   it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation)}
   10: 
(byebug) display @user
1: @user = nil
(byebug)
```

Why is it happening? If I change FactoryGirl to User.create, nothing changes.

Answer (score 3):

in your example

```
before(:all) { @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
byebug
subject { @user }
```

`@user` is `nil`, because byebug interrupts on the level of the definition of the test, not the actual run of the test.

Change it to:

```
before(:all) { 
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user) 
  byebug
}
subject { @user }
```

Btw: you can just write the following to avoid database access and to make the specs faster:

```
subject { FactoryGirl.build(:user) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the line from

```
before(:all) { @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
```

To
    let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

remove subject. Now inspect, you will receive user object in user variable.
This is the best practice.